# Git Reset or Discard or Remove keeps uncommited changes

Tags: git, git-reset, git-revert

Hey i'm having troubles reversing to the latest commit. It keeps saying I have uncomitted changes. I tried:

`git reset --hard HEAD`, 
selecting the files and removing them,
discarding them,
stop tracking them,
i even tried rebranching but that also gives the uncommitted changes error,
They just keep bumping up in my uncommitted changes. Either as a changed file, or a removed file. How do I just revert back to the latest commit, discarding all uncommitted changes in this branch so that I can pull in a new one. this is really grinding my gears since before I never encountered it that I couldn't just undo my changes..

Comment: try `git checkout .` and `git checkout branch-name`

Comment: I've had this happen on a windows box when the .gitattributes file had a strange line ending setting.  You might check in there.

Comment: @Ranjith's tried it butit didn't work aswel, those files won't go away

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely drop the most recent commit, then you should do a hard reset to the commit just *before* the HEAD.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Except if you have already pushed that commit somewherw where it's visible to others. In that case youd' have to `git push --force` afterwards and everyone else would be in a world of hurt the next time they pull and you've rewritten history.

In that case it would be better to simply do

```
git revert HEAD
```